# Sync multiple IDs in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-8

I'm doing a dental function, I'm looking to sync data in a `many-to-many` relationship. I have the following:

```
tooth
- id
- name

cost 
- id
- name

cost_tooth
- id
- tooth_id
- cost_id
- row_number
```

This is the data I got from input checkbox `tooth_id`, I have an array like this

```
[
 0 => [
    1 =>  ["row_number" => 1]
    2 =>  ["row_number" => 1]
    3 =>  ["row_number" => 1]
    4 =>  ["row_number" => 1]
  ]
 1 => [
   1 =>  ["row_number" => 2]
   2 =>  ["row_number" => 2]
   3 =>  ["row_number" => 2]
   4 =>  ["row_number" => 2]
 ]
]
```

my code

```php
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
  $cost_id->tooths()->sync($value);
}
```

I only get the last data but not all the data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p83Mo.jpg)

I know `attach` method can solve for me but I want to try with `sync` method

Comment: The plural of "tooth" is "teeth" btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use sync in loop

```php
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
  $cost_id->tooths()->syncWithoutDetaching($value);
}
```

if you want update version

```php
$sync_value = []
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
 $sync_value[] = $value; 
}
$cost_id->tooths()->sync($sync_value);
```

if you want store version

```php
$attach_value = []
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
 $attach_value[] = $value; 
}
$cost_id->tooths()->attach($attach_value);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved that problem, but now I am still having problem it is the update function, any ideas? help me

Comment: Change my code @LeXuanPhat

Comment: I thank you for your help but the sync method, update the version is not what I imagined @Ramil Huseynov

Comment: How do you want it to be? @LeXuanPhat

Comment: I posted a question. Can you help me? [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74397425/how-to-synchronize-when-updating-records-with-many-duplicate-values)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, here is my code

```php
$output = [
 0 => [
    1 =>  ["row_number" => 1]
    2 =>  ["row_number" => 1]
    3 =>  ["row_number" => 1]
    4 =>  ["row_number" => 1]
  ]
 1 => [
   1 =>  ["row_number" => 2]
   2 =>  ["row_number" => 2]
   3 =>  ["row_number" => 2]
   4 =>  ["row_number" => 2]
 ]
];

foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
  $cost_id->tooths()->sync($value);
}
```

Edit

```php
$output = [
  0 => [
    "tooth_id" => "1"
    "row_number" => 1
  ]
  1 => [
    "tooth_id" => "2"
    "row_number" => 1
  ]
  2 => [
    "tooth_id" => "3"
    "row_number" => 1
  ]
  3 => [
    "tooth_id" => "4"
    "row_number" => 1
  ]
  4 => [
    "tooth_id" => "5"
    "row_number" => 1
  ]
]

foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
  $cost_id->tooths()->sync($value);
}
```

But I still have a problem, it's updating

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).